# How to find user in gitlab on premise using his key

Tags: authentication, gitlab, private-key

My company has `gitlab` on-premise. And I takes over the former project from the previous team. To secure my system from unattended login. I blocks the accounts which are not active members. Unfortunately, I block one access and my `buddy.works` does not work since that account has been block my me.

**Questions:**
How to search the user from given gitlab private key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that private key to push a commit to a project and check on the web interface who is associated to that key.